# Deserialize an object in .NET Core 7.0 which was serialized in .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, binaryformatter, cognex

**Edits**

Due to the (justified) comments about my question lacking code and clarity, I've  added some samples hereunder, however I can't really provide a MWE due to Cognex's vision pro commercial license. Also I didn't make it clear: **I can't change the code behind the classes I need to deserialize.**

**Context**

I am trying to use a commercial image analysis library (Cognex VisionPro) which is written in .NET 4.8 in a C# Blazor application (server-side hosted, .NET Core 7.0). The commercial library has UI components which we don't use in Blazor.

I need to

1. Serialize a file in a .NET 4.8 application (commercial, I can't change it)
2. Deserialize this file in my .NET Core 7.0 application

**My issue**

When deserializing the file (see code hereunder), I get the error

```
// this triggs the error hereunder. I cannot change the code for neither CogToolBlock nor CogSerializer classes.
// reminder, this code is in donetcore 7.0
CogToolBlock toolblock = CogSerializer.LoadobjectFromFile(filePath);
```

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The underlying issue is that binary formatters are obsolete in .NET Core.

**What I tried**

- I saw in [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/306#issuecomment-454190819) that using CoreFX should work but in my case it didn't solve the issue (probably because the object I'm trying to deserialize contains lots of complex types).
- Also, I saw in [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete) that I could still use binary formatters with
  `<EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>`
  but I had no luck with this.
  My idea was to build a small .NET 4.8 app, instantiate an object of the class I'm interested (`CogToolBlock`) and serialize it using `BinaryFormatter`, see the code hereunder:

```
// this whole sequence is in a .NET 4.8 app
var toolblock = CogSerializer.LoadObjectFromFile(@"C:\tmp\sequence.vpp"); 
using (var fs= new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\sequence.vpp.dat", FileMode.Create))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fs, Serialize(toolblock));
}

\\ some more code...

\\ the method to translate my instance to an array of bytes
private static byte[] Serialize(CogToolBlock obj)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter(); // <-- notice I'm using BinaryFormatter
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The above code sequence works and I end up with a "sequence.vpp.dat" which has the same size as my "sequence.vpp" original file.
The problem arises when I'm trying to deserialize this saved file in my Blazor app.

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\tmp\sequence.vpp.dat");
CogToolBlock = Deserialize(fileBytes); 

// ... some code

private static CogToolBlock Deserialize(byte[] data)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream) as CogToolBlock; // <-- ERROR here
    }
}
```

As per @dbc's comment, sure it's been obsolete a long time, but if I had to use it and MSDN says there's a way, it would make sense to try it.

- I'm trying to use google-protobuf, but I can't serialize the complex object (in a desktop .NET application) because :

  > No serializer defined for type: Cognex.VisionPro.ToolBlock.CogToolBlock'

Any idea or pointer would be a great help.

Comment: What kind of thing you want to deserialize? There is no code, so it is hard to understand. It's not clear.

Comment: There are perhaps a dozen serializers you could have used. It appears you are using a binary serializer with SOAP (an odd combination). We'll need more info and some code

Comment: `SoapFormatter` was never even ported to .NET Core, and has been obsolete for a long, long time.  From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter?view=netframework-4.8.1#remarks): *Beginning with the .NET Framework 2.0, this class is obsolete.*

Comment: No code serialization/deserialization code. No serialized file example. It would be hard to help you.

Comment: But it's hard to imagine how you are actually seeing the *`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap'`*.  Is there any chance you could share a [mcve]?  Or even the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, full traceback and inner exception(s), if any?

Comment: Probably you can spin up .NET 4.8 solution and use it as deserialization adapter via some kind of RPC (whichever you prefer).

Comment: I've added some code samples to better explain my situation. Hope it's clearer!

Comment: @GuruStron yes I did exactly that (used `MemoryMappedFile`) but the problem I have is to deserialize the array of bytes[] to my commercial `CogToolBlock` class.

Comment: @Christian you should serialize to some other format. I.e. Comercial app -> .NET Framework adapter (reserialize to json/messagepack/avro/parquet etc.) -> .NET Core app

Comment: @GuruStron you're totally right, however I struggle :)  I've tried json (both NewtonSoft and System.Text.Json) and XML formatters, there's always an error such as `'There was an error reflecting type 'Cognex.VisionPro.ToolBlock.CogToolBlock'.`  The objects I'm trying to serialize implement the `IFormatter` interface I guess, which most newer formatters don't. Although I'm not sure

Comment: @Christian TBH it is hard to tell without actual [mre]. Possibly your also will need to remap types to some adapter ones.

Comment: _"I'm trying to use google-protobuf, but I can't serialize the complex object"_ - if you want to migrate to another binary serializer you can try [this one](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization) (disclaimer: I am the author). It works both in .NET Framework and .NET [Core], and is compatible with the `IFormatter` infrastructure.